# Check if friend relationship already exist

Tags: php, mysql

Why wont this code work? I want to check if the users are already friends before I add.

```
function addFriend() 
{
    global $userid, $friendid;
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE userid = $userid AND friendid = $friendid");  
    if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 1)
    {
        exit("Youre already friend with this user");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO friends (userid, friendid) VALUES ($userid, $friendid)";
        mysql_query($sql);

        if ($sql)
             echo "Success";
        else 
             echo "Failure";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question but `$sql` is never going to be false since you set it 3 lines above.

You may want to change `mysql_num_rows($check) == 1` to `mysql_num_rows($check) >= 1` incase your database does not have any unique constrants on the field pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO friends (userid, friendid) VALUES ($userid, $friendid)";
mysql_query($sql);
if ($sql)
  echo "Success";
else 
  echo "Failure";
}
```

to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO friends (userid, friendid) VALUES ($userid, $friendid)";
mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_affected_rows()) {
  echo "Success";
else 
  echo "Failure";
}
```

See [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Your first version will always return success since you're testing that `$sql` is empty or not and it isn't because you've just assigned a non-empty value to it (being the SQL for the query).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try including the reverse situation in your query too?  I believe the friend table denotes who is friends with who in the order of the request.  So if I request you as a friend, I would be the user, but if you requested me, I would be the friend ID.  So you also need to check where the userid = $friendid and friendid = $userid.

Might that be it?  Hard to tell from your question what exactly is the issue.

NOTE: I am not a PHP expert, so my response is strictly to the Facebook API and not PHP itself.  Just stating before I may possibly get my answer demoted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike B said above, `$sql` will never be false because you set it to the query. You need to set the result of the query to a variable and then test that:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result)
    echo "Success";
else 
    echo "Failure";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

fixed it

didnt have any auto_increcement in friends table